# Is there a tool to verify whether a file with .mp4 extension is exactly in mp4 format?

Tags: mp4, file-format

Anyone knows such a tool?

Answer (score 4):

Try [GSpot](http://www.headbands.com/gspot/), it's a tool that gives you codec information which you can use to see if it's in the `mp4` format.